# Reload javascript only, on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a complex menu system that switches between 'mobile' and 'desktop' menus at 588 px. The mobile system came from codrops, but the desktop system was designed separately. I can modify the codrops, but don't totally understand it. I found several answers on different sites for reloading javascript, but cannot figure out how to reload it with my code. When resizing across the 'border' of 588 pixels, I need the javascript to reload or there are problems with the menus. From desktop to mobile, the functionality of mobile menus doesn't work. From mobile to desktop, get some extra space between the main menu and sub menus. (They resolve if I reload the page, but I don't want to do that.) I am attaching my codrops code (jquery.dlmenu.js) and the code in my pages to call it. Can anyone help with making the javascript reload on resize (or at least when the screen size crosses the 587/588 delineation? This can be seen on this page:http://www.kline.com/Container-Yards/Oakland-CY-Locations-New.asp. My programmers are all waterlogged right now and are unable to help at this time. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
<!--  Page Code at end of pages before Copyright include -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.kline.com/js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
   animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-2', classout : 'dl-animate-out-2' }
  });
 });
</script>
        
<!-- jquery.dlmenu.js code -->

/**
 * jquery.dlmenu.js v1.0.1
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
if ( $(window).width() < 558) {  /* Debug window width (viewport width) = 574 */

;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

 'use strict';

 // global
 var Modernizr = window.Modernizr, $body = $( 'body' );

 $.DLMenu = function( options, element ) {
  this.$el = $( element );
  this._init( options );
 };

 // the options
 $.DLMenu.defaults = {
  // classes for the animation effects
  animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-1', classout : 'dl-animate-out-1' },
  // callback: click a link that has a sub menu
  // el is the link element (li); name is the level name
  onLevelClick : function( el, name ) { return false; },
  // callback: click a link that does not have a sub menu
  // el is the link element (li); ev is the event obj
  onLinkClick : function( el, ev ) { return false; }
 };

 $.DLMenu.prototype = {
  _init : function( options ) {

   // options
   this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DLMenu.defaults, options );
   // cache some elements and initialize some variables
   this._config();
   
   var animEndEventNames = {
     'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
     'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
     'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
     'animation' : 'animationend'
    },
    transEndEventNames = {
     'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
     'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
     'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
     'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
     'transition' : 'transitionend'
    };
   // animation end event name
   this.animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ] + '.dlmenu';
   // transition end event name
   this.transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ] + '.dlmenu',
   // support for css animations and css transitions
   this.supportAnimations = Modernizr.cssanimations,
   this.supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

   this._initEvents();

  },
  _config : function() {
   this.open = false;
   this.$trigger = this.$el.children( '.dl-trigger' );
   this.$menu = this.$el.children( 'ul.dl-menu' );
   this.$menuitems = this.$menu.find( 'li:not(.dl-back)' );
   this.$el.find( 'ul.dl-submenu' ).prepend( '<li class="dl-back"><a href="#">back</a></li>' );
   this.$back = this.$menu.find( 'li.dl-back' );
  },
  _initEvents : function() {

   var self = this;

   this.$trigger.on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {
    
    if( self.open ) {
     self._closeMenu();
    } 
    else {
     self._openMenu();
    }
    return false;

   } );

   this.$menuitems.on( 'click.dlmenu', function( event ) {
    
    event.stopPropagation();

    var $item = $(this),
     $submenu = $item.children( 'ul.dl-submenu' );

    if( $submenu.length > 0 ) {

     var $flyin = $submenu.clone().css( 'opacity', 0 ).insertAfter( self.$menu ),
      onAnimationEndFn = function() {
       self.$menu.off( self.animEndEventName ).removeClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout ).addClass( 'dl-subview' );
       $item.addClass( 'dl-subviewopen' ).parents( '.dl-subviewopen:first' ).removeClass( 'dl-subviewopen' ).addClass( 'dl-subview' );
       $flyin.remove();
      };

     setTimeout( function() {
      $flyin.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
      self.$menu.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout );
      if( self.supportAnimations ) {
       self.$menu.on( self.animEndEventName, onAnimationEndFn );
      }
      else {
       onAnimationEndFn.call();
      }

      self.options.onLevelClick( $item, $item.children( 'a:first' ).text() );
     } );

     return false;

    }
    else {
     self.options.onLinkClick( $item, event );
    }

   } );

   this.$back.on( 'click.dlmenu', function( event ) {
    
    var $this = $( this ),
     $submenu = $this.parents( 'ul.dl-submenu:first' ),
     $item = $submenu.parent(),

     $flyin = $submenu.clone().insertAfter( self.$menu );

    var onAnimationEndFn = function() {
     self.$menu.off( self.animEndEventName ).removeClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
     $flyin.remove();
    };

    setTimeout( function() {
     $flyin.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classout );
     self.$menu.addClass( self.options.animationClasses.classin );
     if( self.supportAnimations ) {
      self.$menu.on( self.animEndEventName, onAnimationEndFn );
     }
     else {
      onAnimationEndFn.call();
     }

     $item.removeClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );
     
     var $subview = $this.parents( '.dl-subview:first' );
     if( $subview.is( 'li' ) ) {
      $subview.addClass( 'dl-subviewopen' );
     }
     $subview.removeClass( 'dl-subview' );
    } );

    return false;

   } );
   
  },
  closeMenu : function() {
   if( this.open ) {
    this._closeMenu();
   }
  },
  _closeMenu : function() {
   var self = this,
    onTransitionEndFn = function() {
     self.$menu.off( self.transEndEventName );
     self._resetMenu();
    };
   
   this.$menu.removeClass( 'dl-menuopen' );
   this.$menu.addClass( 'dl-menu-toggle' );
   this.$trigger.removeClass( 'dl-active' );
   
   if( this.supportTransitions ) {
    this.$menu.on( this.transEndEventName, onTransitionEndFn );
   }
   else {
    onTransitionEndFn.call();
   }

   this.open = false;
  },
  openMenu : function() {
   if( !this.open ) {
    this._openMenu();
   }
  },
  _openMenu : function() {
   var self = this;
   // clicking somewhere else makes the menu close
   $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click.dlmenu', function() {
    self._closeMenu() ;
   } );
   this.$menu.addClass( 'dl-menuopen dl-menu-toggle' ).on( this.transEndEventName, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( 'dl-menu-toggle' );
   } );
   this.$trigger.addClass( 'dl-active' );
   this.open = true;
  },
  // resets the menu to its original state (first level of options)
  _resetMenu : function() {
   this.$menu.removeClass( 'dl-subview' );
   this.$menuitems.removeClass( 'dl-subview dl-subviewopen' );
  }
 };

 var logError = function( message ) {
  if ( window.console ) {
   window.console.error( message );
  }
 };

 $.fn.dlmenu = function( options ) {
  if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );
   this.each(function() {
    var instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu' );
    if ( !instance ) {
     logError( "cannot call methods on dlmenu prior to initialization; " +
     "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
     return;
    }
    if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
     logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for dlmenu instance" );
     return;
    }
    instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
   });
  } 
  else {
   this.each(function() { 
    var instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu' );
    if ( instance ) {
     instance._init();
    }
    else {
     instance = $.data( this, 'dlmenu', new $.DLMenu( options, this ) );
    }
   });
  }
  return this;
 };

} )( jQuery, window );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems like overkill for a menu.. I would suggest you to keep it simple instead.

Comment: There are no script tags for the JavaScript, and considering you used an HTML comment you are most likely using inline scripting and should probably include those...

Comment: I don't think "reloading JavaScript" is ever the answer. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $(window).resize() event handler:
http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(window).resize(function() {

 alert('resized');
 //Add the javascript reload code here

});
```

You can use jQuery.getScript() to reload the javascript https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/